# Disabled entries don't show up in the Linked entries field when displayed in the CP entry list

Tags: control-panel, entries-field

As you can see, I would like to see what challenge the submission is linked to, even though that Challenge might now be turned off (expired or disabled).  Is this a bug or intended behaviour.  Is there an easy way to get this up and running?

If it's intended, I'm not sure why there's a green "enabled" dot on it, there's no way they can be anything else.

In my screenshot, the field Challenge is an entry field and the entry "Challenge #1" is assigned to, but is now expired and not showing in the table.

[image: Example of what's happening]

Comment: "Challenge" is an entries field? If so, in your example is there a "Challenge #1" entry with a status of disabled we're not seeing?

Comment: Yes, exactly (sorry it was not precise enough).  In my screenshot, the entry "Challenge #1" is assigned, but is now expired and not showing in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I agree it's a bit awkward UI-wise in this scenario, but that's currently expected behavior.

You'd probably be able to pull off what you're looking for with a custom plugin by listening to the [getEntryTableAttributeHtml](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#getEntryTableAttributeHtml) hook, though.

In there, you'd check if the passed in attribute is the one for your entries field type, grab the current status and modify the HTML that gets returned based on the status.

Comment: That sounds great, but I have not touched any plugin development yet and already having trouble trying to figure out a group by option.  Adding this to my timeline would be too long.  I found a workaround, using a category instead to assign the entries.  I can even search entries with a specific category, which is not a bad idea.  But it would definitely be a good idea to see the same result in the table as we seen in the actual edit page.

Thanks!